# Stylesheet not appearing

Tags: css, browser

I am trying to add a stylesheet to a website. The stylesheet URL is,
http://www.widgetsinabottle.com/widget/widgetstyle.css

Here is the code in the head for the page,

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.widgetsinabottle.com/widget/widgetstyle.css"/>
```

Here is the website URL,
http://widgetsinabottle.com/widget/demo/effect.html#.UBltBWEe5K3

The problem is that it is not showing the stylesheet when I debug it with firebug.

Here is the code snippet from `<head>`

```
<!-- Include jQuery -->
```

```
<!-- Include Theatre files - I recommend extracting all the Theatre files into "theatre" folder for easier upgrades in the future -->
```

http://www.widgetsinabottle.com/widget/widgetstyle.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

Comment: When you add a `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourHREF" />` you do not need the `<style>` tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me that you have pasted your html code inside an xml document, Get rid of `<?xml version="1.0"?>` at the top of the document.

Comment: Yes. How did you come to know?

Answer (score 4):

Your stylesheet is not valid CSS. Remove these lines from the beginning of the document:

```html
<!-- Design for nicer paging -->
<style type="text/css">
```

as well as these lines at the bottom:

```html
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: Don't forget the two lines at the end (that also have some html).

Comment: oh my! I just pasted it from onpage css.

Comment: I removed it. The problem is still there.

Answer (score 4):

Make your css look like this: (remove everything else, its not valid!)

```
  .paging {
  text-align: center;
  }
  .paging span {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: silver;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
  .paging span.active {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: black;
  }

  .paging2 span {
  font-size: 2em;
  }
  .test {
  text-align: center;
  }
  .test span {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: silver;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
  .test span.active {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: black;
  }

  .test2 span {
  font-size: 2em;
  }
```

Comment: I changed it. The problem still exists.

Comment: In your page, you never link to widgetstyle.css, so Firebug can't find it. Add `<link href='http://www.widgetsinabottle.com/widget/widgetstyle.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />` to your head and that should fix the problem.

Comment: I already added it. I added it again (now its added twice) but it still does not work.